# find the number of corners in image using harris

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

i want to find the number of corners in image using harris detector .

harris detector can find the corners but can,t count the numbers .

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = 'chessboard.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)

#result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)

# Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]

cv2.imshow('dst',img)
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: So you have detected the corners. Now count the number of detections. Do you know about connected components analysis?

Comment: count the number of contours or centroids from the connected components processing. see example at https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html.

Answer (score 0):

The dilation bit is actually very important, although you don't implement the entire story correctly. Specifically:

- The Harris-Stephens filter does not find the corners themselves, it simply computes an image that has high values where a corner is likely to be present in the original image, and low values elsewhere.
- Good guesses for where the actual locations of the corners are the location of the local maxima of the Harris output image.
- An easy way to find the local maxima of any image (including the Harris filter
  output) is to compare it with a dilated version of itself. The maxima are at the pixels that remain unchanged. This is because, by definition, a dilation replaces a each pixel's intensity with the maximum intensity in a neighborhood of pixels around it, and so if the pixel is already at a local maximum it won't change.